# issue starting ffmpeg screen capture on OSX (AVFoundation) from Java

Tags: java, macos, ffmpeg, avfoundation, screen-capture

I would like to launch from Java on OSX a screen capture command like explained here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

It works fine from the terminal. But when I launch exactly the same command using Java's `Runtime.exec` I get the following output:

```
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f892f500400] Video device not found

'1:': Input/output error
```

Assume the command I run is stored as `String cmd = "ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i '1:' output.mkv"`. Things I tried:

- Using `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""` I asserted that `1` is the correct index for the screen. I ran that command also via `Runtime.exec` and it gives the same indexes as when I run it from terminal.
- It does not make a difference whether I use `'1:'` or `"\"1:\""`. Well, in the latter case it says `"1:": Input/output error`. Both variants work in terminal.
- Neither does it make a difference whether I call
  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)`,
  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.split(" "))` or `(new ProcessBuilder(cmd.split(" "))).start()`. In principle it starts ffmpeg and that terminates with the output given above.
- It does not seem to make a difference whether I read out ffmpeg's output or not (via `process.getErrorStream()`)
- The only thing that works is to store the command in a file, e.g. in `run.sh` and then call e.g. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("run.sh")`. It should be possible to execute this properly from Java without this kind of workaround, right? What am I doing wrong?
- On Linux, using e.g. `ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0+100,200 output.mp4` it works fine, from command line or from Java, with `Runtime.exec` and via `ProcessBuilder`.

I did not try it on Windows. On OSX (Mojave 10.14.5) I used Java 12, on Linux (Mint 18, 64bit) Java 8. Would be some hassle to try it with Java 12 on Linux and I suspect the Java version is not the cause, given that avfoundation vs x11grab is the far more dominant difference.

Comment: I'm sure it has to do with the " or some other character - try without "" - also check the output error/ to see what the runtime sees

Comment: The output in the box ``[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f892f500400] Video device not found   '1:': Input/output error`` is already the output error emitted by ffmpeg. As the runtime sees it I suppose. I got it from the process' streams. What else output error do you mean? I tried it with `'1:'` (as mentioned in the post) but get the same result.

Comment: I mean input/output/error streams

Comment: The posted output *is* already that output from the streams. As I said: "I got it from the process' streams". That referred to the `Process` object. I'll give more details: The `InputStream` is totally silent - ffmpeg seems to use the error stream for its entire output. The `ErrorStream` gives the output I posted. I omitted some build info ffmpeg usually emits, e.g. the linked libraries etc., and posted only the actual output. The JVM itself does not output anything as the process runs and finishes normally. I guess it supplies a nonzero exit code but did not check it.

Comment: One more thing I can try is to look for a verbose flag of ffmpeg and run ffmpeg in verbose or debug mode to see if that gives some enlightenment.

Comment: The other thing is to try to get the same response from regular running of the command  on the shell: try to form the command (remove one ", remove : etc) till you get the "[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f892f500400] Video device not found

'1:': Input/output error" - this is hackerism but I dont see any information elsewhere. Then you will probably know what the runtime sees and falters

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
String cmd = "ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i 1 output.mkv"
```

Do not add any quotation marks in the `CMD` string!

If you want to use the input device like below:

```
-i "FaceTime HD Camera"
```

use **string[]** instead of **string**:

```
string[] = {"ffmpeg -f avfoundation","-i","FaceTime HD Camera",
"output.mkv"}
```